# Scraping Facebook Page for Page Likes

Tags: php, facebook, simple-html-dom, scrape

I wrote a simple script for scraping Facebook to get the page likes using Advanced HTML Dom.

```
require_once('../advanced_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("https://www.facebook.com/powerschool"); // you don't need to use curl
$followers = $html->find('._4bl9', 0)->plaintext;

echo "page likes: " . $followers;
```

Although I believe I've targeted the correct class to get the value, the value for followers comes up blank.

Does the page load via AJAX or something and I need to use something like PhantomJS or am I doing this wrong? Thanks !

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook. don´t do that. not sure why you don´t use the api anyway, this IS available with it.

Comment: ok thanks thats the info I needed

Answer (score 0):

Use this construction:

```
<?php foreach ( $html->find( $selector ) as $el ) {
        ?><pre><?php var_dump( $el->innertext ); ?></pre><?php
    }
```